# time series forecasting of time to leave for multiple customers using one model

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, rnn, forecasting

I am a beginner in the domain of forecasting and I was wondering if such a problem could be solved with time series analysis :

> given customer historical data of taxi pickups,along with the weather
>   condition feature, is it possible to analyze their behavior on rainy days and
>   predict their **time to leave**?  (means at what time might a customer x
>   picks up a taxi next time knowing that he went out at 6:42 am
>   yesterday, 7:00 am two days ago, 6:00 am three days ago ...and so on
>   )?

here's how the data looks like globally :

[image]

what I want is to create a model trained on all the customer's historical data, but in the inference phase, it will be used to forecast for one customer at a time.

any guidance on how I can do this? is it a problem that can be tackled with time series? given that the problem here consists of predicting the **time to leave**, unlike their classic usage like sale forecasting and so on.

I would extremely appreciate any advice on methodologies implementing this.